# Bootstrap: fixed vertical position of a responsive column?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to fix the vertical position of a bootstrap column without success.

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12 fixed">
  <div class="row pad-20">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <button type="button" value="0" class="btn {{color1}} btn-lg btn-block choice">{{choice1}}</button>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <button type="button" value="1" class="btn {{color2}} btn-lg btn-block choice">{{choice2}}</button>
    </div>
  </div>    
 </div>
</div>
```

Where fixed is:

```
.fixed{
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 5px; 
}
```

The proportion sm-9 and xs-12 are not respected ... 
Any help?

Comment: Your question is unclear, in what context are you trying to fix the position of this content? In [this example of your code](https://jsfiddle.net/o540r7cf/) it functions as it should be expected to. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It works if you are not in a container. I was.

Comment: You comment does not make it any clearer. The code in both the answer and the link provided above are both inside a container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a `<div class="container">` around the markup you show? Also, in the markup you show there's an extra closing `</div>` tag.

Seems to be working in this JSFiddle I put together:

https://jsfiddle.net/o540r7cf/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12 fixed">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                    <button type="button" value="0" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"> Choice 1</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                    <button type="button" value="1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Choice 2</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5px;
}
```